# Nexus dialer default number

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, phone-app

When using the default dialer on Nexus, you can search contact with the T9 dialpad.

However, I can't seem to find a way to set the defaults for the numbers that come up for each contact. It doesn't look like the default number for the contact is being used. It ends up being very annoying to have to search for the contact and then click the contact avatar bubble and choose the right number.

Anyone know how does the dialer chooses the number to show?
I tried changing the number I want it to show as the "Main" number for that contact, but it still chooses a different number from the numbers list (one that I never use)

#### Edit

To be more clear, I am talking about this number:

[image]

If the contact has multiple numbers, I can't choose what will end up in the dialer

Comment: I don't have a nexus. But I can set default by first visiting the contact in the app. Press and hold the number and select *set default*. I have the same dialer on CM12.1 I suppose.

Comment: Like I wrote, it's a different default and it doesn't fix it

Comment: Which nexus device, and which version of Android?

Comment: @mix3d Nexus 5 / 5X / 6 / 6P, latest Android

Comment: @Michael i think only way is using the search contacts above the favorite/speed dial instead of T9